# como aplicar un reduce en un array tipado de números y letras eliminando anteriormente las letras

Tags: javascript, typescript

Estoy aprendiendo a utilizar TypeScript pero tengo un problema con el siguiente código:

```
const saludo:Array<number|string> = ["hola",0,1,2,3,4];
let nuevo:any;

saludo.shift()


nuevo = saludo.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) =>{ 
  // return accumulator + currentValue
  return accumulator + accumulator
})

console.log(saludo)
```

Me sale el error:

> script.ts(9,10): error TS2365: Operator '+' cannot be applied to types
> 'string | number' and 'string | number'

Lo cual el error es correcto porque el array si esta tipado de esa manera, pero elimine el String dentro del array con el método shift() por lo que el array ya no debería de ser de números y letras, sino solo de números por lo que en teoría debería de poder aplicarse le el método reduce. Si alguien sabe como solucionarlo estaría agradecido.

Comment: Para typescript el type sigue siendo un array de números y strings pese a que elimines el elemento. Puedes forzar al compilador a que lo trate como quieres con la palabra reservada "as": ``(saludo as Array<number>).reduce((a, b) => a + b)``;

Comment: Al fin le encuentro un uso al "as" en typescript, Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te recomiendo adoptar un estilo de programación que haga uso de las mínimas mutaciones. La mayoría de lenguajes tipados funcionan mucho mejor (son capaces de deducir mejor los tipos de las variables y capturan mejor usos erróneos) con valores inmutables.
Forzar el valor de una variable mediante el uso de `as` sólo te servirá para esconder errores que aparecerán en runtime, ya que básicamente estás desactivando el tracking que hace typescript de los typos de las variables y le estás asignando uno nuevo, no es mejor que usar any.

Esta variante de tu código deduce correctamente los tipos y además funciona con cualquier array de `string | number` independientemente de su posición:

```
const saludo:Array<number|string> = ["hola",0,1,2,3,4];

const isNumber = (x: number | string): x is number => typeof x === 'number'

const saludoLimpio = saludo.filter(isNumber)

const nuevo = saludoLimpio.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) =>{ 
  // return accumulator + currentValue
  return accumulator + accumulator
}, 0)

console.log(saludo)
```

[Link a el playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=19&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCGAbArgExALgIICcfwE8AeMZAWwCMBTHAH2hwEswBzAPhgF4YBtAIgAWIRPD4AaAAxiAjGIBMYgMxiALAF0A3ACgtoSLEYQAcuWo4uMABQAPDDFKUaMWnChNWASjvWYh%206adODigCAAcqEAAzGB9OOJgAcgczBJ09aDgkNBAAGUYyUMYQCwQUdAA6SMZEKBpLQxNHHA808AzSKgA3Yu5S7LyCovKcKlRkYCpLS3hgYHJkESgQHDEYObwqMCgANSyqDy42AG8YLRgYAHoLmBGoZBwwGBm5sgX4JfMAajX7ka3dlBUM43Kh3B5PWbzRbLGDfZ5Q97LLQAX1WEhaujawio5UQIBYlj66A8QA)

Comment: Me parece interesante tu aproximación. Lo único es que no estoy de acuerdo que tu aproximación esté exenta o más protegida de esos errores que comentas que solo verás en runtime con la aproximación de usar "as". En tu ejemplo: `const isNumber = (x: number | string): x is number => true` esto seguiría compilando.

Comment: Hombre, si cambias la implementación para que falle, obviamente fallará. Typescript es tan solo una capa sobre javascript, por lo que llega un punto en el que le puedes engañar. No obstante, es más difícil fallar en la implementación de una función tan sencilla comparado a tener que evaluar mentalmente si los tipos que estás asignando son correctos.

Comment: Saludos solo dos pequeños errores sin importancia para el playground, uno sería que el se ponga así console.log(nuevo) para ver el resultado y dentro del reduce poner return accumulator + currentValue, porque tiene return accumulator + accumulator y el resultado es 0 cuando debería de ser 10. de ahí en adelante gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: si, ya me di cuenta de que su código no tenía mucho sentido, pero no me centré en arreglar su lógica, sólo los tipos. Pensé que si quería sumar el acumulador una y otra vez allá el. Es cierto que, al añadir el valor inicial en mi ejemplo el output cambia, pero bueno, lo actualizaré para que tenga más sentido. Gracias